# How can I use instance methods in sequalize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, instance-methods

This is user model and
I want to use verifyPassword instance function from user model in login controller

```
const {Sequelize,DataTypes} =require('sequelize')
const Db =require('../config/mysql_connecton');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const User= Db.define('User', {

    firstName:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    midName:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        
    },
    lastName:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    email:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        unique: true,
        validate:{
            isEmail:true
        }
    },
    contactNo:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        unique: true
    },
    username:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        set(value){
           this.setDataValue('password',bcrypt.hashSync(value, 10))
        }
    }
    
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    instanceMethods: {
        verifyPassword: function(password) {
          return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        }
    }
});
Db.sync()  
module.exports = User;
```

login controller

here I am using verifyPassword instance method to verify password but
getting error like shown below.

```
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports.login = async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        //password - confirm password check at client side
        const user = await User.findOne({where:{username:req.body.username}});
        if(user.verifyPassword(user.password)){
            console.log("kk");
        }
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    }catch(err){
        console.error(`Error in logging  user: ${err}`);
        return res.sendStatus(403);
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error

> error: TypeError: user.verifyPassword is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {Sequelize,DataTypes} =require('sequelize')
const Db =require('../config/mysql_connecton');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const User= Db.define('User', {

    firstName:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    midName:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        
    },
    lastName:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    email:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        unique: true,
        validate:{
            isEmail:true
        }
    },
    contactNo:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        unique: true
    },
    username:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        set(value){
           this.setDataValue('password',bcrypt.hashSync(value, 10))
        }
    }
    
}, 
{
    timestamps: true,
},
{
   instanceMethods: {
        verifyPassword: function(password) {
          return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        }
    }
});
Db.sync()  
module.exports = User;
```

Changed the model format... Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you for this! but now I am using prototype function  just below the Db.sync() and now its working perfect.                                                          ```User.prototype.verifyPassword = function(password) {
   return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
}```

Comment: Okay. That's great.